# Quasar V2 with Typescript - hot reload not working as expected

Tags: typescript, quasar-framework, quasar

Does anyone have problem with HOT RELOAD on a newly created Quasar v2 Typescript ( issue on both webpack and vite ), OSX.

I face the problem then a component gets reactive - q-btn with a :label="" or a q-input with a v-model - other components get "reloaded" as expected.

When start a new quasar 2 project with Javascript everything works great.